# Extrusion along normal is not creating solid object

Tags: modeling

I'm new to Blender and I'll try my best to explain my problem, please bear with me.

[image]

I'm trying to extrude this plane across its normal but the following issue occurs when I try to extrude "inward" in the direction of the curved surface.

[image]

As you can see the resulting object isn't filled in. When extruding in the negative direction the object is a solid. Why is this? I can fill it in manually but it's time consuming and I would like to avoid this in the future.

UPDATE 1:
I forgot to mention in my initial post that I hid a lot of other surrounding vertices, so I was trying to extrude the plane while it was part of another object. Once I duplicated the plane and made it into a separate object, it extruded properly. So I guess the failure to extrude was linked to its position within the larger object...

UPDATE 2:
I then used the Boolean Union tool to reinsert my properly extruded plane into the main object. It worked!

Comment: worth a shot: immediatly after extruding (ie: before de-selecting anything), press `F` to automatically create faces. It might just work?

Comment: No unfortunately, only the bottom plane of vertices were highlighted and it gave me the "Could not create merged face error"

Comment: Check your face orientation. When you extrude you have selected polygons not vertexes, yes? It shouldn't matter if it is a part of a bigger object for the extrusion but may be there is something that would enlighten  the problem, so if you can, post the whole object as well.